# TikZ/Hobby: How to control the smoothness and angles at each coordinate for a closed curve?

Tags: tikz-pgf, hobby

I would like to know how to modify

1. the inward angle,
2. outward angle, and
3. smoothness or curvature

at each coordinate of the following code to make the final drawing look something like this

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (n1) at (0, 0); 
        \coordinate (n2) at (0, 2); 
        \coordinate (n3) at (2, 3); 
        \coordinate (n4) at (3, 3); 
        \coordinate (n5) at (4, 2);
        \coordinate (n6) at (5, 2);
        \coordinate (n7) at (6, 1);
        \coordinate (n8) at (6, 0);
        
        \draw
        (n1) to [closed, curve through = {
            (n2) ..
            (n3) .. 
            (n4) ..
            (n5) ..
            (n6) ..
            (n7)
            } ]
        (n8);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why? IMHO, it makes no sense to use Hobby in this case. Have you actually tried using Hobby's customisation options for this? What do you mean by adjusting the 'smoothness of curvature'? Hobby always tries to draw a smooth curve. That's its raison d'être; it's why it gets up in the morning ;).

Comment: @cfr I just gave Hobby a try. I just need to draw a contour of a car, and Hobby is the first option that came to my mind.

Comment: Well, it would be much easier to help if you would say so. As it stands, I assume you have some particular reason to want to do it this way e.g. you're trying to learn Hobby and the shape is just an example or whatever. Whereas, in fact, you just want a car and that's easy because it's been asked and answered before. If you just search for `car`, the question is in the top couple of results.

Comment: Dammit. I forgot proposing a duplicate would close your question immediately. My apologies. Ping me if you don't agree it's a duplicate and I'll try to get it undone.

Comment: @cfr No worries. I think the cited answer can give what I need. Thanks for the help.